# How do I get notified by email when I receive replies to my question? And how do I respond to those replies?

Tags: support, questions, notifications

When someone replies to my question:

1. How can I be notified by email that a reply is waiting?
2. How can I reply to them? I see no REPLY icon next to their name which would let them know I have a follow-up to their response.

I cannot find a NOTIFICATION icon (for me) or a REPLY icon (for my responder) to alert me or them.

Comment: This is not a forum; you are not supposed to reply, although you can post comments to ask for clarifications etc.

Comment: There _is_ an inbox notification; whether you are receiving inbox notifications by email is controlled from your personal profile preferences, which we cannot see.

Comment: See also [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/158281)

Comment: Doesn't (or didn't) the question wizard say something about receiving notification by email the next day (indirectly signalling a ***wrong*** timescale of 24 hours for interactions on Stack Overflow)?

Comment: My question was referring to when I am not at 'the page in the head'...which is 99% of the time unless I'm told to go there.

Comment: @user3216617 The header is always visible (unless you fiddled with the CSS or something), so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 3):

You are already notified about replies when you are at the page in the head

[image]

You can go to profile settings, then Edit email settings and change your email settings:

[image]